# Can XCode work with TFS?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, team-foundation-server, xcode

We have been using Team Foundation Server (TFS) for source code management of our solution which contains components for a number of platforms - asp.net, windows & android so far. We now wish to develop iOS apps for the solution but is there any integration possible between XCode and TFS?

What's the best way to use TFS version control with Xcode now that I find out we need to write some iOS apps?

We will also eventually want to have automated builds for a Continuous Integration process

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I can tell only what I experienced, it might not be the answer. It worked with us only on very basic level. With merges it is wasn't automatic, we used external tool instead. I can provide sort of just an opinion: use something else if it is allowed. TFS works well with microsoft things, we couldn't really use it comfortably with Xcode

Comment: I looked into doing this via SvnBridge but never got it working perfectly and we ultimately abandoned the goal of getting the Mac guys on the same version control system as the Windows guys. But my question [Mac Subversion client that works with SvnBridge to TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224975/mac-subversion-client-that-works-with-svnbridge-to-tfs) may give some pointers. Xcode's built-in SVN support + SvnBridge might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use TFS inside Visual Studio, though Microsoft seems to prefer this "buy one, get one for full price plus SQLServer and CALs" solution :)

You can access TFS from an external source control. They have a Windows Explorer plugin that works much like TortoiseXXX products, allowing you to commit and update directly from the filesystem icons.

They also have a [command line source control interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg413282%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for Linux, called "Team Explorer Everywhere", and one that plugs into Eclipse.

It is [available to use with Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785) OS 10.8+, but on Intel only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The newer Team Foundation Server versions support Git, so if you set up your TFS repository to use git, you can easily use TFStogether with the build-in git version control tools in Xcode.